# How do I get to ellipses to display on a React Native <Text> element using numberOfLines that's being clipped on a line break?

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

In React Native, I have a `<Text numberOfLines={5}>` element that is working properly, but not when the text gets clipped right before a line break.

For example, in this screenshot, the first section is working fine, but in the second section, there is a line break immediately after "Transport:" and then the text is continued, but React Native isn't displaying ellipses so users won't know that there is text being clipped.

[image]

Is this possible? I saw some [PRs for the Text prop lineBreakMode](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6339), but it doesn't look like it's been released yet. Would that prop would solve this issue? Is there an easy way to do this in the current version of React Native?